# How to pull updates from remote branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-pull

There is remote branch: `R`

There is local branch: `L` (which was created based on `R`)

So the graph is

```
 R--R1---R2---  
 \           
  L--L1--
```

Right now, I just need keep `L` branch always have the updates from `R`

What is the simplest way I can do this?

I think the answer is to:

1. pull updates from local R first
2. checkout to L and merge

But this does not seem very straightforward and I need do some conflict handling manually.

Answer (score 2):

You want to make L a tracking branch for R.  You can do this with the command.

```
git branch --track L remote/R
```

Then, any time you are on branch L, just run `git pull remote` and it will pull updates and automatically merge them into your repository.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches

Comment: I don't think he want to L to track R. L is just a local branch that the OP uses for local development and that the OP wants to sync with the latest changes on R. If L would track R, then he could push directly from L to R, which might not be what the OP wants.

Comment: Thanks all you guys !  My intention is to keep local branch L relating to remote branch R, so "git branch --track L origin/R" should work , right ?  (only difference is origin replace remote )

Comment: Yes.  "remote" is the name of the remote repository.  I don't deal with remote repos much, so my syntax might be slightly off.  Please correct me if it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can pull directly into L from R. Assuming L is checked out:

```
git pull origin R
```

L doesn't have to be tracking branch for you to pull in remote changes.